# Potentially undefined behaviour in C

Tags: c

I need to know if the following code could be an undefined behaviour (I'm pretty sure it is):

```
int main(){
   int z=53;
   z=z<<=3;
   return 0;
}
```

This was a question in a classroom test.  I told my teacher I thought it was UB, but my teacher did not believe me.

Comment: Does it even compile? Doesn't look like it (line 3).

Comment: I'm not sure about C11, where assignment has sequencing implications C99 (and before) didn't have. Which standard are you interested in?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?  Just write sensible code that has no possibility of UB.

Comment: It looks like UB to me. Modifying `z` twice between sequence points.

Comment: Yes, it does compile, but there are two assignments between two sequence points..  I am interested in C99 standard.

Comment: I'd have to know what you're actually trying to do in the code.  That's the problem with code that skirts UB; nobody really understands what it actually does.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Probably trying to find out if it is UB? You  know,  creating an MCVE and all that?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Lifetimes are squandered cogitating over things like this.  Just write sensible code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree with that. But it is good to understand when UB happens in C, especially because similar expressions in other languages are well defined. OTOH, there are a zillion duplicates out there.

Comment: If you write sensible code, you *never* have to wonder about things like this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But you might sometimes consume code that is not your own. And have to identify UB and fix it.

Comment: Actually, it's not my code. I had the question about it during a test and I told it to be UB, but my teacher doesn't believe :(

Comment: it can be considered for **Educational Purposes** ! after all we learn from our fault even if it is a useless code @RobertHarvey

Comment: @user300234 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69157/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-user300234).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's  undefined. Reffering to N1256, C99 draft, subclause 6.5/2 (emphasis mine):

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified **at most once** by the evaluation of an expression. 72) Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to
>   determine the value to be stored. 73)

Comment: Do you have any idea about the previous standards please ??

Comment: @Meninx: You mean C90 Standard, right? Yes, this rule is actually the same (second paragraph within 6.3 Expressions).